# Collecting the most Fruit on a Grid

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms

There is a grid of size `WIDTH` * `HEIGHT`.

`X` fruits are randomly distributed on the grid.

Each player is randomly placed on the grid.

The game runs for `X / 2` turns.

Each turn, a player can move left, up, right, down or not move at all. At the end of each turn, the fruits on each player's square are added to their score, removed from the square and randomly re-spawned somewhere else.

What can I do to maximise the number of fruits collected?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help with conceptual problems but just solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really help you.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've tried looking at the 4 adjacent grid squares and working out their "potential", which I did by looping over each grid square and adding the number of fruits, divided by the distance, to said adjacent square. I then picked the adjacent square with the highest potential value- that gave worse results than randomly walking around for some reason. Edit: that reason is them getting stuck in a local minimum and going left, right, left, right continuously.